# ionic v1 storing token in service not working angularjs

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, angularjs-service, angularjs-factory

I'm trying to store a token from a login service in a variable, to retrieve it later and add it to the header in order to be able to consume more services from the API. I'm able to login and get the token but it is not getting saved when I try to get it back from the variable I'm storing it in, not too sure what I'm doing wrong as there are no syntax mistakes. Any help is appreciated. Here's my code example:

1. services.js

   ```
   .service('loginService', function($http, $ionicPopup, $window) {

     var token = '';

     return {

      login: function(username, password, practicePin){

        var url = 'https://localhost/login';

        var parameter = JSON.stringify({username:username, password:password, pin:practicePin});

        $http.post(url, parameter).then(function(response){

            token = response.headers()['token'];

            var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
              title: 'Welcome ' + username,
              subTitle: token
            });

            alertPopup.then(function(res) {
              $window.location.href = 'home.html';
            });

        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          $ionicPopup.alert({
            title: 'BAD CREDENTIALS'
          });
        })
      },

      getToken: function(){
        return token;
      }
     }
   })
   ```

At this point, the token is saved in the variable [as the picture shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Q75m.png)

But then when I try to get the token back from the controller, it is empty.

```
.controller('FindSlotCtrl', function($scope  , $ionicPopup, $state, loginService) {

 $scope.login = function(username, password, practicePin) {

   loginService.login(username, password, practicePin);

 };

 $scope.token = function(){

   $ionicPopup.alert({

     title: 'TOKEN -> ' + loginService.getToken()

   });

 };
}
```

[Here's the second alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nz4rW.png) and the token variable seems to be empty, I tried to store in an array, the first time I execute .length of the array is equals to 1, but then on the second alert it would show me length = 0.

I also tried to set and get the token from another service/factory and injecting it in the loginService but I was getting the same result eitherway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I was able to get the result that I wanted by using the $window.localStorage, might not be the best way to solve it, but at least I could make it work. Here's the code example:

1. service.js

   ```
   .service('loginService', function($http, $ionicPopup, $window) {

   return {

     login: function(username, password, practicePin){

       var url = 'https://localhost/login';

       var parameter = JSON.stringify({username:username, password:password, pin:practicePin});

       $http.post(url, parameter).then(function(response){

        var token = response.headers()['token']

        $window.localStorage['token'] = token;

        var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({

            title: 'Welcome ' + username

        });

        alertPopup.then(function(res) {

          $window.location.href = 'home.html';

        });

       }).
       error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
           $ionicPopup.alert({
             title: 'BAD CREDENTIALS'
           });
        })
       }
     }
   })
   ```
2. controllers.js

   ```
   .controller('FindSlotCtrl', function($scope, $window, $ionicPopup,loginService) {

     $scope.token = $window.localStorage['token'];

     $scope.login = function(username, password, practicePin) {

      loginService.login(username, password, practicePin);

     };

     $scope.tokenAlert = function(){

        $ionicPopup.alert({

          title: $scope.token

        });

     };
   })
   ```

   Picture of the second screen after logging in

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On the first alert you can see the token because your token is retrieved from the server. When you call getToken() later, it returns an undefined value because the token is, well, undefined.

In order to be able to reuse the token, have the login function in your service return the token, like so:

```
login: function(username, password, practicePin){

 var url = 'https://localhost/login';

 var parameter = JSON.stringify({username:username, password:password, pin:practicePin});

 $http.post(url, parameter).then(function(response){
     return response.headers()['token'];
 }).
 error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
   $ionicPopup.alert({
     title: 'BAD CREDENTIALS'
   });
 })
```

}

Then, in your controller save the token:

```
$scope.login = function(username, password, practicePin) {
    $scope.token = loginService.login(username, password, practicePin);
};
```

Then, you can alert it simply this way:

```
$scope.alertToken = function(){
   $ionicPopup.alert({
     title: 'TOKEN -> ' + $scope.token
   });
 };
```

Comment: it doesn't seem to work as expected, even tho I'm returning the token from the header.           
 $ionicPopup.alert({
              title: response.headers()['aerona-auth-token']
            });
  return response.headers()['aerona-auth-token']; 
The alert is showing the token, but then on the controller when I try to set it on a variable, it says undefined:
    $scope.login = function(username, password, practicePin) {
      $scope.token = loginService.login(username, password, practicePin);
       $ionicPopup.alert({
          title: ' - ' + $scope.token + ' - '
        });
    };